# Can't work with VMSS because of nonexistent apllication gateway

Tags: azure

Can't do anything with VMSS because it has pointer to nonexistent application gateway (in [VMSS/Networking/NetworkInterface/LocadBalancing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UewU.png)):

When I try to restart/upgrade VVMS I get an error.

Error example:
*Failed to restart virtual machine scale set 'aks-agentpool-xxxxx-vmss'. Error: Resource DEV-GATEWAY referenced by resource MC_DevGroup_dev-cluster_westeurope/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/aks-agentpool-xxxxx-vmss was not found. Please make sure that the referenced resource exists, and that both resources are in the same region.*

Comment: Have you configured AKS with the application gateway integration?

Comment: Yes, there was an application gateway, but I had have removed it, and then happened this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems is solved, steps:

1. Create new AG in same dev group and region and name as AG in VMSS (in my case DevGroup, West europe, "dev-gateway")
2. Add backend pool to this AG (name should be same as name in VMSS/Networking/NetworkInterface/LocadBalancing, in my case name is "aks")
3. Add empty backend pool with one rule (it could be pool which points to some random ip address)
4. Wait ~10 minutes
5. Remove backend pool created in second step
6. Run upgrade command for all (in my case just one) virtual machins in VMSS
7. Remove AG created in first step